# Remove div elements using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Code:**

```
 <div id="wrap">
 <div>Hello</div>
 <H1>world</h1>
 </div>

 <button id='btn'>Delete</button>
```

I need to remove contents inside div->#wrap 
on button click.
***the result should be like***

```
<div id="wrap">
</div>
```

**I tried using**

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $( "#wrap" ).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.html('')` or [`empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) to empty the `div`

```
$('#wrap').html('');    //$("#wrap").empty();
```

`remove()` will remove it from the DOM.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wjgahkLk/)**

*<sub>Also fix `<H1>world</h1>` to `<h1>world</h1>`</sub>